# I want my signup button to go back to login after clicked

Tags: java, android-studio

*Hello I encounter some problem in this code, after signing up I want it to back to login so user must verify first the email and then login before entering the app but when I click my btnSignUp it goes directly to my home activity.
Here is the code:*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXYfI.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0VWJ.png)

```
btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = edtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String pass = EdtPass.getText().toString().trim();
            String confpass = edtConPass.getText().toString().trim();
            if(email.isEmpty() || pass.isEmpty() || confpass.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(pass.length() <7 || !pass.matches(confpass)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password must above 7 characters or your password entered does not match.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                firebaseauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            sendEmailVerification();

                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to register.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });


}
private void sendEmailVerification(){
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseauth.getCurrentUser();
    if(firebaseUser!=null){
        firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Verification email sent, Verify and login.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(signUp.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to send email verification.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(signUp.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Since this block of code available in your ***sendEmailVerification*** method, it will start MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks I already solved my problem there is just inconsistency on my recycleview